# Divs wont stay inline chrome extension

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

Its not just divs. Lists also wont stay inline. I've already tried many things and cant get it to work. (display: inline on everything and making the wrapper width 100%) Is this something normal for chrome extensions? Here's my html, i hope you can help. Thanks!

```
<!--
<!doctype html>
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Minds radio</title>
    <style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 900;
height: 1100;
display: inline;
font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
background-color: white;
width: 900;
}
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    p{
            visibility:visible;
    }

a {
color: #5882C4;
}
.footer {
display: inline !important;
width: 100%;
}
.bloc {
padding: 20;
display: inline;
background-color: black;
}
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">
<center>
<img width="260" height="170" src="http://themindspanel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mindsradio3-1200x500.jpg"  alt="mindsradio3" /></a>
<center><iframe src="https://mindsradio.airtime.pro/embed/player?stream=auto&amp;title=Minds Radio" width="280" height="216" frameborder="0"></iframe></center>
</center>  
<div class="footer" style="display: inline !important; width: 100%;">
  <div><a href="index.html" class="bloc">Radio</a></div>
  <div><a href="schedule.html" class="bloc">Schedule</a></div>
  <div><a href="donate.html" class="bloc">Donate</a></div>
  <div><a href="mindsPanel.html" class="bloc">M-P</a></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add min-width:

```
<!--
<!doctype html>
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Minds radio</title>
    <style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 900px;
height: 1100;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
background-color: white;
}
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    p{
            visibility:visible;
    }

a {
color: #5882C4;
}
.footer {
display: inline-block !important;
width: 100%;
}
.bloc {
padding: 20;
display: inline-block;
background-color: black;
min-width:200px
}
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">
<img width="260" height="170" src="http://themindspanel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mindsradio3-1200x500.jpg"  alt="mindsradio3" /></a>
<center><iframe src="https://mindsradio.airtime.pro/embed/player?stream=auto&amp;title=Minds Radio" width="280" height="216" frameborder="0"></iframe></center>
</center>  
<div class="footer" width: 100%;">
  <span><a href="index.html" class="bloc">Radio</a></span>
  <span><a href="schedule.html" class="bloc">Schedule</a></span>
  <span><a href="donate.html" class="bloc">Donate</a></span>
  <span><a href="mindsPanel.html" class="bloc">M-P</a></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The widths you are using are the actual problem. Show us a Fiddle.

Comment: `display:inline-block` and a `min-width:200px` will do.

Comment: add min-width:200px to the footer class? If so it didnt change anything.

Comment: Still didnt work but they dont spread father apart downwards. Also, do you want screenshots?

Comment: Screenshots would be great.

Comment: This is the latest code you sent. I just hid the picture and iframe. https://s32.postimg.org/mcm5vv81x/Screenshot_from_2016_07_02_15_43_32.png

Comment: There was an extra <center> tag which was not closed. I am assuming this was causing the issue.

Comment: I fixed that and i still have the inline problem. https://s31.postimg.org/nu6ick1qj/Screenshot_from_2016_07_02_16_07_43.png